# Seeking a GNSS data to be use for my work

Tags: data, imagery, download

I would like to understand what GNSS is used for? Can I download it from the website and use it for my work? I am not familiar with it. Does it come with the GPS?

Does it come with horizontal accuracy that can I use to verified the points on the surface?

If GNSS is not the case, then what other option do I have for the data that I need?

Comment: One question per Question, please.

Comment: @Vince    Did I give too many questions on m part ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> GNSS stands for Global Navigation Satellite System, and is the
>   standard **generic** term for satellite navigation systems that provide
>   autonomous geo-spatial positioning with global coverage. This term
>   includes e.g. the GPS, GLONASS, Galileo, Beidou and other regional
>   systems. GNSS is a term used worldwide **The advantage to having access
>   to multiple satellites is accuracy, redundancy and availability at all
>   time.**

https://www.semiconductorstore.com/blog/2015/What-is-the-Difference-Between-GNSS-and-GPS/1550

To use GNSS you need a device that can support all the GNSS frequencies and software to capture your data for processing the signals.

An example (there are others) is a device called bad elf pro
https://bad-elf.com/pages/be-gps-3300-detail

> Stationary high precision GNSS as low as 1m out of the box with PPP in
>   regions with SBAS coverage.

(*disclaimer have used this device in the field with good results in the sub $500 budget)